# How can I Autoload Spring Security when modified from screen

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, rbac

I am working on a RBAC model for my Ecommerce website. In this, there will be multiple clients who will be registering to my website. For each client there will be different database created.

For each database. There will be User, Role and Permission table. There will be an admin who can add user and assign role to user. Also the admin of the account can add role and modify role. This changes should be done once the clients update from panel. And will be reflected after user re-login into panel.

Now the Spring boot Security Configuration is loaded at the time of startup of server. How can I apply security to user runtime.

I had created a RBAC project in my local. Created model for Users, Roles and Permissions. I had a SecurityConfig class defines the security for user in system. Code is as below

```
package com.rhv.config;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.rhv.um.model.Role;
import com.rhv.um.service.RoleService;
import com.rhv.util.Utill;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/um/roles", "/um/users/{\\d+}",
                    "/um/users", "/um/permission").hasAuthority("Administrator");

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

In this I want the roles and permission coming from database. If the user is logged-in, then security for the user should be loaded automatically. If there is any change in Role or permission by Admin. The same should be reflected to user, once the user re-login into the app.

Edited (19 Sep 2019): UserDetailsServiceImpl is as below.

```
package com.rhv.um.service.impl;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.rhv.um.model.Role;
import com.rhv.um.model.User;
import com.rhv.um.service.UserService;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username does not exists: " + username);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
    }

}
```

I had added UserService class which is fetching the User object from the database. User object is having relationship with Role. Role is having relationship with permission. Please find the UserServiceImpl code as below

```
package com.rhv.um.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.rhv.um.model.User;
import com.rhv.um.repository.UserRepository;
import com.rhv.um.service.UserService;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your `userDetailService`?

Comment: Please check. I had added UserDetailsServiceImpl

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441621/spring-boot-with-spring-security-and-custom-database/41443500#41443500) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692956/how-to-give-authorities-for-users-with-java-spring-security/53693023#53693023) maybe help

Comment: Hello @chaoluo, Thanks for the reply. As stated in the UserDetailsServiceImpl, roles are automatically added and removed from the user's GrantedAuthority. But when adding the permission into role are not reflected on runtime. Thus I want to achieve this.

For Example: 
I had created a Role named "Operation Admin" and I added 10 permission in it(like "p1", "p2", .. "p10"). Now I had assigned "Operation Admin" role to user (say "John Doe"). Thus this permission and role should be reflected to user once he re-login into the system.
This is what I want to achieve

Comment: As you can see in my Security Config class. The permission and role are hard coded in configuration. But i want it dynamically to fetch them from database and auto create the configuration. Code as here: http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/um/roles", "/um/users/{\\d+}",
                    "/um/users", "/um/permission").hasAuthority("Administrator");

Comment: You can use the `jdbcAuthentication` to load roles from DB, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692956/how-to-give-authorities-for-users-with-java-spring-security/53693023#53693023

Comment: Yes. I am loading roles from the database I am using JPA to load user from the database using username. I had edited the question and added my UserServiceImpl class which loads Users. Also each user is having relationship with role. Thus role are also fetch from the database and the role are added into GrantedAuthority. But I am stuck at assigning permission to role dynamically. What if admin removes a url from the role. Then this should be reflected to all user who are having that particular role. I Hope you understand my exact issue. Let me know if I can help you more understanding  question

Comment: I am trying to achieve something that is shown in the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9l_Hn8qzsYw

Comment: please see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-dynamic-url-metadata)

Comment: Thanks for the support. I had not got the solution to my problem. Your lastly shared link was helpful to me. Also there is another stackoverflow question that helped me the most. Click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456717/spring-security-custom-filterinvocationsecuritymetadatasource-implementation-403"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had got the solution to this problem. I have to implement the spring's FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource and AccessDecisionManager

Below is my FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource that returns Allow/Deny of ConfigAttribute.

```
package com.rhv.um.filter;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterInvocation;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.rhv.RegistrationApplication;

public class MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
        HttpServletRequest request = fi.getRequest();
        HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(fi.getRequest().getMethod());

        // Bypassing Security check for /js, /css and /images url
        if (new AntPathRequestMatcher("/js/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/css/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/").matches(request)) {
            return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Allow" });
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                .getAuthorities();

        try {
            for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
                if(grantedAuthority.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Administrator")) {
                    return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Allow" });
                }

                for(String allowedUrl : RegistrationApplication.permissions.get(grantedAuthority.toString()).get(httpMethod)) {
                    if(new AntPathRequestMatcher(allowedUrl).matches(request)) {
                        return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Allow" });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Deny" });
        }

        return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Deny" });
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

The return type of MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource is used by MyAccessDecisionManager class that implements AccessDecisionManager. Below is the code for MyAccessDecisionManager

```
package com.rhv.um.filter;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

public class MyAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
            throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
        if (configAttributes == null || configAttributes.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Iterator<ConfigAttribute> ite = configAttributes.iterator();
        if(ite.next().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Allow")) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The above code will decide, Should the user have access to a particular url or not. I had handled it with Allow/Deny ConfigAttribute.

Finally is my SecurityConfig Class code that provides the implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Below is the code for SecurityConfig

```
package com.rhv.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.rhv.um.filter.MyAccessDecisionManager;
import com.rhv.um.filter.MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(
                        O fsi) {
                    FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource newSource = new MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource();
                    fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(newSource);
                    fsi.setAccessDecisionManager(new MyAccessDecisionManager());
                    return fsi;
                }
            })
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    private void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

This implementation helps me to dynamically permit user to access url.