# why does spring security ignore request interception

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a question: Why is it that when `getAttributes()` returns `null`, every subsequent request doesn't go through the `MyFilterSecurityInterceptor` class and it doesn't intercept for the next request or every request after that?

MyFilterSecurityInterceptor

```
@Service
public class MyFilterSecurityInterceptor extends AbstractSecurityInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyAccessDecisionManager(MyAccessDecisionManager myAccessDecisionManager) {
        super.setAccessDecisionManager(myAccessDecisionManager);
    }


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        FilterInvocation fi = new FilterInvocation(request, response, chain);
        invoke(fi);
    }

    public void invoke(FilterInvocation fi) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //There is a blocked url in fi
        //Call the getAttributes(Object object) method of MyInvocationSecurityMetadataSource to get all the permissions corresponding to fi
        //Call the decide method of MyAccessDecisionManager to verify whether the user's permissions are sufficient
        InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(fi);
        try {
            //Execute the next interceptor
            fi.getChain().doFilter(fi.getRequest(), fi.getResponse());
        } finally {
            super.afterInvocation(token, null);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSecureObjectClass() {
        return FilterInvocation.class;

    }

    @Override
    public SecurityMetadataSource obtainSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return this.securityMetadataSource;
    }
}
```

MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource

```
public class MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    @Override
    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
        HttpServletRequest request = fi.getRequest();
        HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(fi.getRequest().getMethod());

        // Bypassing Security check for /js, /css and /images url
        if (new AntPathRequestMatcher("/js/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/css/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/**").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/").matches(request)
                || new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2/**").matches(request)) {
            return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Allow" });
        }

        try {
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getAuthorities();
            for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
                if(new AntPathRequestMatcher(grantedAuthority.toString()).matches(request)) {
                    return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Allow" });
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return SecurityConfig.createList(new String[] { "Deny" });
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

MyAccessDecisionManager

```
public class MyAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
            throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {

        if (configAttributes == null || configAttributes.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Iterator<ConfigAttribute> ite = configAttributes.iterator();
        if(ite.next().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Allow")) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Access is denied");
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

config security

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyFilterSecurityInterceptor myFilterSecurityInterceptor;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().formLogin()
                .addFilterBefore(myFilterSecurityInterceptor, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

and I have set a breakpoint in debug to check, it really only stops on the first request, and after return null is returned incoming requests are not stopped

[image: Debug info]

Answer (score 1):

So, I think it is because your checked exception in your filter. Returning null is not enough significant.

If I were you, I will use a RuntimeException which will stop the workflow at that moment, add these exception inside the webapplication exception handler and make a custom webpage to display a message for these exception or for all requests with 403 http status code (not authorized).

Did you add your custom interceptor inside your Spring application config ? Inside the main file : `SpringWebapplication.java` as a Bean :

```
@Bean(name="securityInterceptor")
public MyFilterSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    return new MyFilterSecurityInterceptor();
}
```

Or inside `WebConfig.java` :

```
private MyFilterSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor;
//...
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(securityInterceptor);
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can you be more detailed on this idea. I don't understand why when `null` is returned, any subsequent requests don't go past the break point I'm setting.

Comment: first of all, did you check you have added your custom interceptor inside your Spring Application Class or Config ? I will update my answer soon.

Comment: It is inside your `SecurityConfig` file. But is it sufficient to work if not added to the stack of interceptors first ?

Comment: if set config as you said it requires `HandlerInterceptor` but i implements `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` and it is `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, all config I put in `SecurityConfig` above

Comment: i followed this tutorial [link](https://programming.vip/docs/5ddd73623debe.html) and there is another post about `FilterSecurityInterceptor` on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991065/how-can-i-autoload-spring-security-when-modified-from-screen).

Comment: 2 posts have different return in `getAttributes()`. If you return `List<ConfigAttribute>` as the data type of this function, then all Interceptors are logical and return `AccessDecisionManager.decide()` but if you return `null` then all subsequent requests are not logical this again. If you can run the above code then you will understand my question

Comment: The last link you have provided has a good solution for your implementation choice. And you can seek some information in documentation too : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.4/reference/html5/ I am working now can't help more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was wondering why `null` makes `FilterSecurityInterceptor` not work then

Comment: From official documentation : "Alternatively you could provide a null implementation of the SecurityContextRepository interface, which will prevent the security context from being stored, even if a session has already been created during the request."
@see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html, it's the last section words. So we you are returning null, no context si stored so nothing is evaluated and your application continues to work without other security filters : the security chain is broken.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I think need to understand a lot more about spring